Webpack Module Execution Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
I have an Angular app that acts as the host and imports a React/Nest.js component using Module Federation. I'm encountering the following error
    Error loading or rendering the React component: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
    at options.factory (VM118 remoteEntry.js:879:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM118 remoteEntry.js:82:33)
    at VM118 remoteEntry.js:1230:162
    at __webpack_require__.m.<computed> (VM118 remoteEntry.js:1241:31)
    at options.factory (VM118 remoteEntry.js:879:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM118 remoteEntry.js:82:33)
    at fn (VM118 remoteEntry.js:516:21)
    at eval (react-jsx-dev-runtim…evelopment.js:17:13)
    at eval (react-jsx-dev-runtim…velopment.js:1295:4)
    at ./node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js (node_modules_react_j…-runtime_js.js:18:1)

The angular webpack configuration is this:
    const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "hostTest",
    publicPath: "auto",
    scriptType: 'text/javascript',

  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
    sideEffects: false,
    minimize: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  devServer: {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization'
    },
    hot: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        library: { type: "module" },


        remotes: {
          "v_foo_component": "http://localhost:3001/_next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js",

        },

        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          react: {
            singleton: true,
            eager: true,
            requiredVersion: 'auto',
          },
          'react-dom': {
            singleton: true,
            eager: true,
            requiredVersion: 'auto',
          },
          'tailwindcss': {
            eager: true,
            requiredVersion: false,
            singleton: true,
          },
          'postcss': {
            eager: true,
            requiredVersion: false,
            singleton: true,
          },
          'autoprefixer': {
            eager: true,
            requiredVersion: false,
            singleton: true,
          },
          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })

    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};

and the react/nest.js is this
const {NextFederationPlugin} = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf');
const packageJson = require("./package.json");

const remotes = (isServer) => {
    const location = isServer ? 'ssr' : 'chunks';
    return {
        host: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
            ? `host@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/${location}/remoteEntry.js`
            : `host@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/${location}/remoteEntry.js`,
    };
}

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    eslint: {
        ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
    typescript: {

        ignoreBuildErrors: true,
    },
    webpack(config, {isServer}) {
        config.plugins.push(
            new NextFederationPlugin({
                name: 'v_foo_component',
                filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
                exposes: {
                    // specify exposed pages and components
                    './FooComponent': './src/components/FooComponent/index.tsx'
                },
                remotes: remotes(isServer),

                extraOptions: {
                    automaticAsyncBoundary: true,
                },
                shared: {
                    ...packageJson.dependencies,
                    react: {singleton: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: packageJson.dependencies.react},
                    "react-dom": {
                        singleton: true,
                        eager: true,
                        requiredVersion: packageJson.dependencies["react-dom"]
                    },
                    'tailwindcss': {
                        eager: false,
                        requiredVersion: false,
                        singleton: true,
                    },
                    'postcss': {
                        eager: false,
                        requiredVersion: false,
                        singleton: true,
                    },
                    'autoprefixer': {
                        eager: false,
                        requiredVersion: false,
                        singleton: true,
                    },

                },
            })
        );

        return config;
    },
}

module.exports = nextConfig

I have checked for any syntax or runtime errors in the module but I cannot understand what the problem is.
